# Does python Sha1 takes integer

Tags: python

How to take integer in hashlib.sha1(int).
Please see the code in which i am taking IP as string converting it as integer now at hash.sha1 doest take integer...

```
 import hashlib
 import socket
 import struct
  class blommy(object):
   def __init__(self):
    self.bitarray= [0]*2048

  def hashes(self,ip):
    #convert decimal dotted quad string to long integer"
    intip= struct.unpack('>L',socket.inet_aton(ip))[0]
    index = [0, 1]
    hbyte = hashlib.sha1(intip) # how to take sha1 of integer??
    index[0] = ord(hbyte[0])| ord(hbyte[1])<< 8
    index[1] = ord(hbyte[2])| ord(hbyte[3])<< 8
```

---

Need to convert this C code to python. Please advice some part of code is written above. If i take ip as int I cannot compute sha1 + even if convert ip using socket than sha1 dont accept it suggestion? see comments below

```
//fixed parameters
k = 2

m = 256*8

  //the filter
  byte[m/8] bloom   ## 

 function insertIP(byte[] ip) {

byte[20] hash = sha1(ip)

int index1 = hash[0] | hash[1] << 8 # how to in python?
int index2 = hash[2] | hash[3] << 8

// truncate index to m (11 bits required)
index1 %= m  ## ?
index2 %= m  ## ?

// set bits at index1 and index2
bloom[index1 / 8] |= 0x01 << index1 % 8   ## ??
bloom[index2 / 8] |= 0x01 << index2 % 8   ## ??
}

 // insert IP 192.168.1.1 into the filter:
    insertIP(byte[4] {192,168,1,1})
```

Comment: There's no such concept as the sha1 digest of anything besides a sequence of octets;  what are you really trying to do?

Comment: This is what i am trying to do can you see this c code ? parameters
//filter
k = 2
m = 256*8
//the filter
byte[m/8] bloom   ## What is this part?
function insertIP(byte[] ip) {
    byte[20] hash = sha1(ip)
    int index1 = hash[0] | hash[1] << 8
    int index2 = hash[2] | hash[3] << 8
    // truncate index to m (11 bits required)
    index1 %= m  ## ?
    index2 %= m  ## ?
    // set bits at index1 and index2
    bloom[index1 / 8] |= 0x01 << index1 % 8   ## ??
    bloom[index2 / 8] |= 0x01 << index2 % 8   ## ?? }

 // insert IP 192.168.1.1 into the filter:
 insertIP(byte[4] {192,168,1,1})

Comment: please add the new code to your answer; it's unusuable in comment form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is no, you can calculate the hash of strings but not integers. Try something like:

```
hashlib.sha1(str(1234)).digest()
```

to get the hash of your integer as a string.